# Looking for some way to monitor the error and crash on Unity

Tags: android, exception, unity-game-engine, crash, monitor

I want to design a feature for my Android game built by Unity, that while app is running, it can collect the crash or exception information. After that, I could try to get the error log to judge whether the app meets some exceptions and be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set setUncaughtExceptionHandler to Activity thread  check this:

1][uncaughtexceptionhandler](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/threads/uncaughtexceptionhandler/thread-uncaughtexceptionhandler-example/)

2][handle-force-close-and-other](http://techin-android.blogspot.in/2011/05/handle-force-close-and-other.html)